# .htaccess redirect "domain.com/wp-content/uploads/..." -> "sub.domain.com/uploads/..."

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain, redirect

I changed the directory of my Wordpress media library from /wp-content/uploads to sub.domain.com/uploads and now I would like to redirect the URL of already indexed images to the new URL.

This code is not working...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^wp\-content\/uploads\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/subdomain\.domain\.com\/uploads\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

... and I'm not sure why. Would be great if somebody could help me here.

Comment: try to not escape the characters `.`, `:`,`-`and `/`

Comment: Still not woking unfortunately.. Maybe there is a conflict with this?

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

or because I'm using https for the site?